# Ask twice for email in the Ubercart checkout page

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, ubercart

Is there a Ubercart module to ask the user to insert his email twice in the checkout page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt there is a module for this. You can do this with `hook_form_alter` in a custom module. Should only be 10-20 lines of code.

Something like

```
function module_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['...']['second_mail'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Verify E-mail'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#weight' => xx,
  );

  $form['#validate'][] = 'module_validate_function_name';
}

function module_validate_function_name(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if ($form_state['values']['mail'] != $form_state['values']['second_mail']) {
    form_set_error('second_mail', t('You have mistyped your e-mail, please verify');
  }
}
```

The above is example code, but might actually work, it depends how the ubercart checkout form is created, more specifically, the name of it's mail field.

There are a few blanks but it should be easy enough to fill out.

Answer (score 2):

There is an email confirmation checkbox in ubercart checkout settings. No additional modules needed.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by using this:

```
/* Code to add confirm email for uc checkout */
function custom_code_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    if($form_id == "uc_cart_checkout_form" && $form['panes']['customer']['primary_email']['#type'] != 'hidden'){    
        $form['panes']['customer']['primary_email']['#weight'] = '0';
        $form['panes']['customer']['new_account']['#weight'] = '2'; 
        $form['panes']['customer']['confirm_email'] = array(
            '#title' => t('Verify E-mail address'),
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#size' => '32',
            '#required' => true,
            '#weight' => '1'
        );
        $form['#validate'][] = 'custom_code_validate_confirm_email';
    }
}
function custom_code_validate_confirm_email(&$form, &$form_state){
    if($form_state['values']['panes']['customer']['primary_email'] != $form_state['values']['panes']['customer']['confirm_email']) {
        form_set_error('panes[customer][confirm_email', t('Email addresses must match.'));
    }   
}
/* end code for confirm_email */
```